# How can I simplify too many AND/OR in ruby

Tags: ruby

Below is my code. How to simplify this code?
I just want to avoid too many `&&` conditions.

Suppose I've two url:

```
ipt_string = www.abc.com/catogories/profile/heels/

ipt_string = www.abc.com/me/payment/auth/

    def to_uri(ipt_string)
        point = ipt_string.gsub('{', '#{')
        if @profile && 
           !point.include?('/catogories/') && 
           !point.include?('/profile/') && 
           !point.include?('/heels/') && 
           !point.include?('/me/') && 
           !point.include?('/payment/') && 
           !point.include?('/auth/')
        { ... }
```

Comment: def to_uri(ipt_string)

    point = ipt_string.gsub('{', '#{')

Comment: is it a String?

Comment: yes. if i hit the uri.. whether the uri contains all the strings or not. just want to check this

Comment: Hit the uri? All the strings? Please provide some context, I have no idea what you are talking about :-)

Comment: suppose i'm hitting an uri's endpoint .. & i want to check whether the mentioned strings are present on that endpoint or not

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I mean an example of your input. How does a typical `ipt_string` look like?

Comment: [link] (https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/heels/pr?sid=osp,iko,6q1&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Heels)

suppose i'm hitting the above url & i want to check whether it contains "heels" or not.. like this..

Comment: Do you want to check whether that URL contains the string `"heels"` or whether the HTML document contains `"heels"`?

Comment: whether the url contains 'heels'

Comment: And what about an URL containing the string within another word, e.g. `flipkart.com/wheels/`. Should it match or do you want to match whole words or maybe whole path segments only? (the latter would involve splitting the URL into its components)

Comment: i want to match **/heels/** only

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. You should add the information from the comments to your question and edit your example code to reflect your actual problem (i.e. provide a value for `ipt_string`, use `'/heels/'` instead of `'a'` etc). Furthermore you should either clarify what this `gsub` is about or remove it from your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First option:

```
if @profile && (%w(a b c d e) & point.split('')).none?
```

Other option would be to use a regex:

```
if @profile && !point.match(/[abcde]/)
```

As @Stefan pointed in comments, somewhat shorter version:

```
if @profile && point !~ /[abcde]/
```

---

As to the OP comment on the checking

> whether the url contains `'/heels/'`

Since it is a specific string of characters you're looking for, I think checking for inclusion would do:

```
if @profile && !point.include?('/heels/')
```

## EDIT

Having a `list_of_strings` that you want to check for within a `point`, you could go with:

```
if @profile && list_of_strings.none? { |str| point.include?(str) }
```

Comment: A string without spaces would fail the first test, no?

Comment: @lcguida indeed, it ought to be `.split('')`, edited, thanks!

Comment: @Stefan indeed shorter :)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I assume each of the strings is actually a path segment.

Comment: suppose there are 5 strings like '/heels/'   .. so i can't always use **.include?**

i want to optimize this..

Comment: @J.Adhikari as you can see, your question is still unclear. There are probably various ways to solve it, and I'd like to see more answers. So please take the time to edit your question.

Comment: yes. each of the string is actually a path segment.@Stefan

Comment: @J.Adhikari I've edited the answer for the case of multiple path's segments.  Have to leave for a short while now

Comment: @AndreyDeineko how to write all the path segment into `list_of_strings`

i've modified my code. can you suggest how to write all the path segment into `list_of_strings` .

Comment: @J.Adhikari yeah, just create an array: list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

Comment: @J.Adhikari make sure to accept the answer if that's working (checkmark on the left of the answer)

Comment: what does `none?` do?  if it was `point.include?('/catogories/')` then what i can do?? @AndreyDeineko

Comment: @J.Adhikari Check [Enumerable#`none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` with a regular expression:

```
> "a string of text".match(/[abcde]/).nil?
 => false
> "a string of text".match(/[zq]/).nil?
 => true
```

Comment: I suggest `'pet' !~ /[abcde]/ #=> false; 'pot' !~ /[abcde]/ #=> true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @profile && (/[abcde]/.match(point)).nil?
```

or

```
if @profile && (/[abcde]/ =~ point).nil?
```